# Do MySQL locks expire?

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking

Using InnoDB. I've read [this article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking-transaction-model.html) about the InnoDB locking model, but I could not find the answer to this question:

Do MySQL locks expire? If a process grabs a lock, will that process still hold the lock tomorrow?

My use case is what if my program has a rogue thread running, maybe it's killed, maybe it's alive. Is there any guarantee that that the lock will be released...ever?

Comment: Check this [Maximum Transaction Timeout at MySQL Forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,651421,651421#msg-651421). I guess the answer continues to be *no, they don't*. The locks would expire when the transactions expire, and there's no timeout for them. I don't know if the transactions would abort when the client connection is lost, but even that doesn't seem to be sure...

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Honestly a specification for this would be nice even if the verdict is non-deterministic

Comment: There are many types of locks.  Please provide more context of what you are seeing.  Also see `innodb_lock_wait_timeout`, which defaults to 50 seconds.